# Instalação de pacotes

Tags: xamarin, nuget

Precisei copiar uma classe inteira para dentro de meu projeto PCL(Xamrin.Forms). E está dando erro em três using que são:

using System.Web;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

Tentei instalar via NuGet e não estou conseguindo.Diz não ser compatível com um projeto PCL

> Não foi possível instalar o pacote 'System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0'.  Você
>   está tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto que se destina a
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111',  mas o pacote não
>   contém nenhuma referência de assembly ou arquivo de conteúdo que seja
>   compatível com essa estrutura.  Para obter mais informações, entre em
>   contato com o autor do pacote.

Como resolvo isso? Preciso dessas DLL's pois há referências a elas no projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Se a classe tiver mudado de projeto, você deve alterar os `using`,  observando se os projetos que vão utilizar a classe possuem referência ao projeto em que ela está escrita, e também observar o namespace da classe e se a ela está acessível externamente (pública). Fica mais ou menos assim: `using NomeProjeto.NameSpace` ou diretamente `NomeProjeto.NameSpace.Classe.Metodo`